# Is this parabolic induction?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory

In [one of my previous questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1337950/irreducible-representations-of-operatornamegl-3-mathbbf-q), @PL. explained the idea of parabolic induction. In my bachelor thesis I used a technique quite like this, to find all irreducible representations of a certain group. I wonder whether the following technique is actually parabolic induction or something that rather looks like it.

> Let $H$ be a non-abelian finite group such that $V := H/Z(H)$ is abelian. Let $\pi$ be the projection onto $V$. We know the following: Every irreducible representation of $H$ is of the form $\operatorname{Ind}_L^H(\rho)$ where $\rho$ is a character of a subgroup $L$ and $Z(H) \subsetneq L \subset H$. We also know that this representation $\rho$ is of the following form: $$\rho(l) = \psi \circ \pi(l)$$ where $\psi$ is a character of $Z(H)$.

In this sense, $\rho$ is just a character on $L$ that we get by inflating a character of $Z(H)$. If we then induce $\rho$ from $L$ we get an irreducible representation. There is a clear analogue in this situation to the situation in parabolic induction. Is there a name for this type of induction, and also, why does this so often work?

(Some extra detail that might help: I used this technique to give a (simper) proof of the Stone-von Neumann theorem for finite Heisenberg groups)

Edit: Rereading my question, I notice that I may not have been very clear. Let me therefore give a concrete example.

> Let $H:= H(\mathbb{F}_q)$ defined as $$H(\mathbb{F}_q) := \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & a & c \\ 0 & 1 & b \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix} \  \middle | \  a, \, b, \, c \in \mathbb{F}_q \right\},$$ and let $\psi: \mathbb{F}_q \to \mathbb{C}^*$ be a character of $\mathbb{F}_q$. The subgroup $L$ we are looking for is $$L := \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & c \\ 0 & 1 & b \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix} \  \middle | \  b, \, c \in \mathbb{F}_q \right\}.$$ We 'inflate' our character $\psi$ in the following way: Look at $f: L \to \mathbb{C}^*$ defined by $$f \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & c \\ 0 & 1 & b \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix} = \psi(c).$$ We can prove that $\operatorname{Ind}_L^H(f)$ is irreducible for all $\psi$.

This search for irreducible representations looks a lot like the search for the principal series that was explained in the aforementioned answer to my previous question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't parabolic induction. The group in your example is a connected unipotent group, so there's no hope whatsoever of performing induction from a smaller reductive subgroup in the way that you would in parabolic induction.

This is really just taking advantage of the fact that your group is somehow "very close to being abelian".

Comment: Is it a common technique in representation theory to 'inflate' representations (or characters) before inducing them, or is it just a coincidence between these two cases?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "common technique". Whenever you have a representation of a quotient group, you can obviously inflate it. I don't really know of anywhere other than parabolic induction where  it's as central to the classification though; that comes from Levi subgroups being as special as they are. What you're really doing here is extending the action of a representation by the centre, letting the central character be trivial. That everything is obtained in this way comes from your group being nearly abelian.